# Android xml - preferences - change color

Tags: android

Welcome.

I have a list of preferences and have the "Change background color" I want to use "color picker" AmbilWarna. I know how to implement it. But how do the preferences that you click to open a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple dialog it would be a `List Preference`

Comment: But I do not want to stiff colors just want to give colors to choose from a palette.

Comment: you will need to make a custom activity /preference activity. Create a activity and then just save the users selection in shareprefs